# Vue run function from child component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have html like this:

```
<div id="nav">
    <homenav v-on:navigation="switchNav(this.nav)" v-if="nav == 'homeNav'"></homenav>
    <mainav v-if="nav == 'mainNav'"></mainav>
</div>
```

My Js is like this:

```
Vue.component('homenav', Navigation);
Vue.component('mainav', Navigation2);

   new Vue({
    el: '#nav',
    data: {
        nav: 'homeNav'
    },
    methods: {
        switchNav: function (test) {
            console.log(test);
            console.log(this.nav);
        }
    }
});
```

Part of homenav component to show what I want to do:

```
<template>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Website Builder</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/#/">Create</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a v-on:click="navData"  class="nav-link" href="/#/how">How</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/#/about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/#/youtube">Videos</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/#/login">Go to main site</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            nav: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
    navData () {
        this.nav = 'mainNav';
        this.$emit('navigation');
        console.log(this.nav);
        }
    }
}
```

So what I am trying to accomplish here is a dynamic switch in navigation, for example if user click on Go to main site link the nav would change from homenav to mainav dynamically. However, I don't know how to accomplish it and my attempt is above. Help..

Edit so in my newest attempt I have managed so that it console log from child + parent function. it consoles homeNav and mainNav together. However I need to also pass the child this.nav to parent so parent can update it's this.nav? Because at the moment despite it outputting both, navigation doesn't change.

Comment: You'd use [events](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events) or a state management system like [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html).

Comment: I think I tried using events unless I am doing it wrong, can you provide an example on my code with either of those method or both if possible?

Comment: Show us how you attempted the events.

Comment: code that I have attempted is above

Comment: There's no code related to events above. Read the link I provided and implement accordingly.

Comment: As an alternative to events or Vuex, you could set a localStorage key and render the appropriate navigation based on the key value.

Comment: @ceejayoz check my newest attempt, hopefully you can point me further

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve that is using **Vue Router**.

But, if you want to do that without routing you should do it with **Dynamic Components**

```
<component is=""></component>
```

You can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/lucaskatayama/256Lo0xa/1/

There is an App, with a button to toggle a component inside `<component></component>`.

It simulates your switch, by changing the selected component.

Comment: The only problem is that the button needs to be inside the components itself as it a link inside navigation. I am using vue router however vue router is controlling another div with the content, i.e where everything else goes. so if I go to /something content changes. But of course navigation doesn't use router unless I can define same routes? i.e if /something both content and navigation changes

Comment: Do you want a component that is loaded dynamically where the button that switches the component is inside that component?????????

Comment: pretty much that is the case

Comment: That makes no sense to me... if you put the button inside ... there is no way to switch because the button is not there!1